# Google Data Studio functionality I couldn't find

Tags: looker-studio

I started using Google Data Studio today and it's looks pretty friendly and simple for me but I couldn't find some functions.
How to make prebuilt data filtering? Like default table misses some values and then user turns them on. I found out only about filter control, but I can't make default values there, they all are true by default. Also, I noticed about table filtering but that thing can't be turned off by user in view mode.
And the second question. Is it possible to make on table click event? Like make a click on some value and then the table shows only rows where values are equal to clicked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It an be achieved using the `Default Selection` feature in [Filter Controls](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/6312144).

**Multiple Items**:
To add multiple items, use a comma `,` as the separator.

**Escape `,`**:
If the value that needs to be captured includes a `,` use `\,` to escape the `,` so that the `,` is treated as a regular character.

Added a [Google Data Studio Report](https://datastudio.google.com/reporting/9568a003-8173-4c75-a5b3-5944071a62de) and GIF to elaborate:

[image]